# Implementing "dumb" input components in mobx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

In a React application, most components should be "dumb", aka they should not be aware they are part of your application, and should have generic properties that allow them to be re-used in other applications.

For example, I might have a "dumb" form component like this:

```
function MyForm(props){
    return (
        <form>
            <input type="number" value={props.value}/>
        </form>
    );
}
```

When I then add a "smart" (state-aware) component on top of this, I can make it aware of the mobx state with `observer()`:

```
import { observer } from "mobx-react"
import React from "react";

import myStore from "./store";
import MyForm from "./myForm";

const MyApp = observer((props) => {
    const store = React.useContext(myStore);
    return (
        <MyForm value={store.formValue}>
    );
});
```

However, my form component also needs to be able to update the state, since it's an input. However, if `MyForm` is to stay "dumb", it can't access the store, and it can't assign a value to its props, because that would make no sense outside of mobx. How then can I create a "dumb" input component in mobx that is able to update store state?

Comment: call the update function passed from it's parent?

Comment: That would mean creating an update function for every piece of state I might want a component to update, though

Comment: create a single function and pass name field and value as params just as you would do in normal forms example

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: You have made the question so dramatic, there is one and only one way, a reusable component (as you call them dumb) should receive a callback function from the parent and call that whenever wants to change the sate. though the sate is local, Mobx, Redux ...

Comment: And if you use a correct naming convention, you can have only one function for changing all input values (onChange), and one probably onSubmit function. So, there are a few functions that should be passed.